# 5v relay module and bulb holder

Tags: arduino-uno

[image][image]

Hello sir , so can i cut the switch from the picture and connect the wires to my relay module ? Im sorry because im still learning . Thank you !

Comment: If you are still learning I would recommend you start with something more basic like LEDs instead. And learning the basic concepts of electricity from there. Not mains power that can kill you in case of mishandling.

Comment: Thank you sir @Coder_fox i will be carefully handling this project :)

Answer (score 1):

A relay is nothing more than a switch - but instead of your finger controlling it, it's controlled by an electromagnet.

The relay can perform the exact same function as the switch on that cable.  In the image you have posted you would use the right-hand two screw terminals (middle is "common", right is "normally open") to replace the switch.

Comment: So that means , it works right if i do like that sir @Majenko ? Thank you sir for the help ! :) Your are kind !

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to this to cut the switch [image]

If you are a beginner, you can [get started with Relay here](https://arduinogetstarted.com/tutorials/arduino-relay)

NOTE: It's dangerous and can cost your life. Please be careful when using Relay with 220 VAC

Comment: Thank you sir . You r kind ! Will do , thanks again I relay appreciated it !